# Effect of different graph operations on spectrum of graph laplacian?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

The [algebraic connectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_connectivity) of a graph G is the second-smallest eigenvalue of the [Laplacian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) of G. This eigenvalue is greater than 0 if and only if G is a connected graph. The magnitude of this value reflects how well connected the overall graph is.

for an example, "**adding self-loops**" does not change laplacian eigenvalues (specially  algebraic connectivity) of graph.
Because, laplacian(G)= D-A is invariant with respect to adding self-loops.

*My question is:* 
Does anyone has studied effect of different operations (such as edge contraction) on spectrum of laplacian?
do you know good references?

Remark1: the exact definition of the algebraic connectivity depends on the type of Laplacian used.  For this question I prefer to use Fan Chung definition in [SPECTRAL GRAPH THEORY](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fan/research/cb/ch1.pdf). In this book Fan Chung has uesed a rescaled version of the Laplacian, eliminating the dependence on the number of vertices.

Remark2: I asked this question before at [cstheory.stackexchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5439/effect-of-different-graph-operations-at-algebraic-connectivity-of-graph-laplacian), but now I think here is more appropriate for that.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question a long time ago, the best reference given to me is an interlacing theorem by Chen, et. al. which says that the eigenvalues of the (normalized) Laplacian of a graph $G-e$ are interlaced by the eigenvalues of the graph of $G$.

http://epubs.siam.org/sidma/resource/1/sjdmec/v18/i2/p353_s1

Answer (score 2):

You can start by looking up the classical 1994 survey by Merris:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379594904863

There is a lot of newer work that has been published since then, but I think that Merris's paper is still a good introduction.

Comment: The OP is interested in the normalised Laplacian, whereas Merris discusses the classical graph Laplacian, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to plug my own work here in case people still stumble on this post: ["Deletion-contraction for a unified Laplacian and applications"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.13949), by F. Aliniaeifard, V. Wang and S. van Willigenburg, describes the effects of edge deletion and contraction on Laplacian eigenvalues. In particular, we note that there is a deletion-contraction recurrence on the level of graph Laplacian characteristic polynomials when we allow for vertex weights, which leads to interlacing eigenvalue theorems.